# Email keyboard in alternative mode (when digits are visible)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, virtual-keyboard

I have a `UITextField` where sip connection data can be entered. So for example:

`2342452@somedomain.com`

In general problem is that this looks like an email, but for 90% of cases user will enter numbers first.
So I've set email keyboard, but I would like to activate alternative keyboard mode, so digits would be visible when keyboard is shown (see picture):

[image: email keyboard second mode]

Is it possible?

Comment: This link may help you.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150077/ios-toggle-default-keyboard-from-abc-mode-to-123-mode-via-code

Comment: but this works in opposite direction (from alternative mode to main mode). I want start editing with alternative mode of keyboard. (it is not my idea, some one has this strange requirement)